# I cant install ChromeDriverManager with ChromeDriverManager().install()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I've been learning Python for 2 month, and this error has never occurred to me once but all of a sudden I can't download CHROMEDRIVERMANAGER and whenever I get to its website to download it manually it says
This XML file does not appear to have any style information. The document tree is shown below.
The error:
`
`Access Denied`
Access denied.

> We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

> `Access denied` 
>    Access denied.
>    We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location

`
this is the error that I am getting trying to download CHROMEDRIVER
I believe its because my code requests to download CHROMEDRIVER the error pops up the same one that pops up when I try to download it
My code

```
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pyautogui
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import random
import numpy as np
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
options=options)
driver.get("https://www.pinterest.com/ideas/")
```

apparently, something is wrong with the line where I said what is the driver

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the below line from:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
options=options)
```

**TO:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(version="114.0.5735.90").install()),options=options)
```

Above should solve your issue. Having said that, with latest selenium(`v4.6.0` or above), you don't really need `ChromeDriverManager` to download/handle browser drivers. Selenium's new tool known as `SeleniumManager` will do what `ChromeDriverManager` used to do. So the code now can be simplified as below:

```
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.pinterest.com/ideas/")
```

References - [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install Chrome driver.
You can use your chrome installed in your pc.
I can share my some code. Please try like this.

```
import pkg_resources
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, "chromedriver.exe")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=chromeOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running an outdated version of `webdriver-manager`.

Execute `pip install webdriver-manager==4.0.0`