# new Selenium Manager is not updating ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

chms_values_csv = '/Users/daneweickert/Downloads/entering Chms values - VOLLEYBALLL (3).csv'

chms_values = pd.read_csv(chms_values_csv)
```

Terminal Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 112
Current browser version is 115.0.5790.114 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

I am a novice programmer. I tried this solution but am not sure what is wrong
[Chrome Driver Manager not working on Chrome Version:115.0.5790](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76770921/chrome-driver-manager-not-working-on-chrome-version115-0-5790)

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing `This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version...` then your version of `selenium` is out-of-date. Upgrade to the latest version (currently `selenium` `4.10.0`), which will get the correct driver for you via Selenium Manager. (Selenium Manager is fully functional at `4.10.0` for Chrome versions up to `115`)

Due to driver restructuring by the Chromium Team for the new [Chrome-for-Testing](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/), the old driver page, https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads, only goes up to version `114`. The next version of `selenium` will start to get `chromedriver` from the correct location. (Thankfully, `chromedriver` `114` is still good enough for Chrome `115`.)

Comment: Thank you for replying Michael. I am using selenium 4.10.0 which is why I'm so confused.

Comment: If still an issue, try removing your ``chromedriver`` ``112`` so that it has to get a newer one.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I replaced my chromedriver version with 114 and that solved the problem