# Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver-manager

I have recently updated my selenium framework to work with WebDriver manager. Previously, I was manually setting up the chromedrivers/ gecko driver versions as per my use. I am facing this error when I try to run my test in CICD pipeline (GitLab runners).

Test works fine manually (my machine/ VM) but it throws error when I execute it via CICD.

```
        String browser = new PropertyReader().readProperty("browserType");
        String browserMode = new PropertyReader().readProperty("browserMode");

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();    

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            prefs.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[]{"Chrome PDF Viewer"});
            prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
            prefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
            prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[] { "enable-automation" });
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.addArguments(browserMode);
            options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
            options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");

            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driverThreadLocal.set(driver);
```

BrowserMode is set to "--headless" and browser is chrome from config properties.

Error logs from CICD GitLab:
[image]

Comment: Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76752843/7598774

Comment: This has to specify the chromedriver. Whereas I am using web driver manager here which should cater installing and configuring the driver itself. Also, its working fine manually but failing on CICD executions.