# Error on Python Selenium Script (Cannot Connect to Service)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting the following error on my script, chromdriver.exe being the problem:

> File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in start
> raise WebDriverException(f"Can not connect to the Service {self._path}")
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service C:\Users\usernamehere.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win64\123.0.6312.58\chromedriver-win32/chromedriver.exe

I have tried the code below and also referenced the path to chromedriver in my C drive, both methods return the same error, this points to my code being wrong.

```
options = Options()
options.headless = False
options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,576")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=options)
```

If the code looks fine the only other thing I can think of currently is my laptop now has "Admin by Request" on it and i'm wondering if it could be interfering with chromedriver.exe in the C drive.

Comment: Check this answer if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: There can be 2 problems. First one is the path to the ChromeDriver, second one is your Chrome and ChromeDriver versions are different. Please check both versions.

Comment: Check this answer too - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76752843/7598774

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Shawn I changed my code to both options but still no luck, getting the same errors, selenium is version 4.18.1, webdriver manager is version 4.0.1 so I have the right version for the edit but still the same

Comment: @MuhammedSamedÖzmen thanks for your reply. My chromedriver version matches my chrome version so there should be no issues there. The path is fine too when I use a path. In the code above it installs the correct version of chromedriver for you and works from the path it installs it at so versions are not the issue