AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities' while executing python script
I'm new to Python coding. I just finished installing Python, Pycharm, Selenium and configured Driver manager.
And when I run my first program I'm seeing below error message. Code attached below. Please help. Thanks.
Please go through attached image.
And the error I'm seeing is:
"C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe" C:\Users\...\...\BOFA.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 87, in driver_location
    browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\...\Desktop\...\BOFA.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\vtadu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
    msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

Process finished with exit code 1

And I looked into some of the suggestions provided, it says it's Python issue because it's reading as None. But not sure how to come out of this scenario. Really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

please do not post images of code! they're much harder for the commnity to discover, search, and reproduce errors from! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Remove the string ChromeDriveManager().install() from the 6th line.
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://bankofamerica.com/")
#driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(6)
print(driver.title)


...and remove the import ChromeDriverManager line because it's no longer needed.

When I remove  ChromeDriveManager().install()  and                  import ChromeDriverManager, I see below error message.

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 123.0.6312.123 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Stacktrace:

The chromedriver version (114.0.5735.90) detected in PATH at C:\Users\vtadu\OneDrive\Desktop\WhatsApp\chromedriver.exe might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (123.0.6312.123); currently, chromedriver 123.0.6312.122 is recommended for chrome 123.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry

Do you believe that the call to ChomeDriverManage.install will correct the version discrepancy? If not, it's likely that the version incompatibility is the next problem and you research it separately / raise a separate question.

I think so, when I use ChromeDriverManager.install() it's complaining about above issue. And when I take out ChromeDriverManager.install() then I see version mismatch issue.

Below article solved my issue. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76749878/i-cant-install-chromedrivermanager-with-chromedrivermanager-install
